# Button, created in Androids Layout XML, don't shows up in findViewById(R.id

Tags: android, button

I have created a button in an XML File in Androids Layout folder and now i want to add an OnClickListener. The problem is findViewById(R.id.addNewMission) don't gets accepted. Spelling is 100% correct. I have already cleaned the project.
What to do now?

Best Regards

It's a fragment.

```
                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Create new Mission" />

                            <TableLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Missionname" />
                                    </LinearLayout>
                                </TableRow>

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:ems="10" />
                                </TableRow>

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                                </TableRow>

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/textView4"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Target Person" />

                                        <EditText
                                            android:id="@+id/editText5"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:ems="10" >

                                            <requestFocus />
                                        </EditText>

                                        <Button
                                            android:id="@+id/choosepic2"
                                            android:layout_width="110dp"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="Choose Picture" />

                                    </LinearLayout>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableLayout>

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/addNewMission"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Add Mission" />

                        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml code and activity code.

Comment: Is you findViewById inside an activity?

Comment: I don't see any `android:id="@+id/myButton` in your layout XML...

Comment: The my button should just demonstrate it. THe button is called addNewMission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Fragment`:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             View lView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
             mButton = (Button) lView.findViewById(R.id.button_name);
             mButton .setOnClickListener(...);

        return lView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This forum is really awesome. I have never gotten any responses, that fast. :)